# Is it possible to give command to switch / router and read the result using raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, switches, networkmanager

Is it possible to give commands to switch / router and read the result using raspberry pi ?

As a part of my project, i need to monitor the switches/routers of my network by printing commands on the Command prompt and read/detect the result that shows in the command prompt.

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Hello and welcome -- This question is not related to raspberry pi but, Yes, you can do it simply by python and access to the router/switch by SSH/TELNET.

Comment: In addition, I have experience in creating a monitoring software and if you are looking for getting state of devices, I recommend using SNMP and NetFlow to get information.

Answer (score 0):

If your router supports ssh, then you can pass commands via ssh (your public key should be on the router)

```
/usr/bin/ssh asus /usr/sbin/ip addr show eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" {gsub(/\/.*$/, "", $2); print "Asus", $2}' >>~/tmp/ip 2>/dev/null
```

will log into your router and issue "ip addr show" and save the WAN ip on your local system.